# Beautiful Soup Scraping - Python - Recursion Limit?

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup

Struggling with a piece of code that seems to work as it should but hits a recursion error before it completes.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("list.csv", header=0) 

areaList = list(data.a)
pageNum = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
S = set()

def linkscraper(indexvalue):
    n = 0
    while indexvalue < 221 and n < 5:
        req = Request("https://www.someurl.com/search_location="+areaList[indexvalue]+"&page="+pageNum[n], headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
        html = urlopen(req).read()
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
        for link in bsObj.find_all(href=re.compile("searchterm")):
            S.update([link["href"]])
        print(len(S))
        n += 1


    linkscraper(indexvalue+1)


linkscraper(0)
```

Since the recursive function call happens only 221 times, I thought the recursion limit default for python was at least 2000 times? Any clue as to what is going? Apologies in advance if the answer is very obvious, still quite new!

Comment: Why are you using recursion?

Comment: Haha you're right, I shouldn't be using recursion here... I just realised I could use another while loop to encase the the whole block. Thanks